# How do you read and write a name and its value in a specific file in python?

Tags: python, linux, io, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I want to read a file and get the RSSI value from the file.

Here is what is in the dumpscan.txt file, with the RSSI and value in it looks like:

```
HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 15
    LE Advertising Report
        ADV_IND - Connectable undirected advertising (0)
        bdaddr B4:99:4C:64:33:E0 (Public)
        Flags 0x05
        RSSI: -72
HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 15
    LE Advertising Report
        ADV_IND - Connectable undirected advertising (0)
        bdaddr B4:99:4C:64:33:E0 (Public)
        Flags 0x05
        RSSI: -70
```

As you can see there are multiple RSSI values. I want to get them all and output them to a file.

I know the logic but cannot piece together the commands on how to extract the RSSI values in the file. Here is a code with some logic (which is not correct):

```
dumpfile = open("dumpscan.txt","r")
dr = dumpfile.read()
for x in dr:
        if x=="RSSI:" & its value in dr:
            print RSSI and its value,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `regex`

```
    import re
    fi = open("dumpscan.txt", "r")
    lines = fi.read()

    regex = re.compile('RSSI:\s(\-?\d+)')
    out = regex.findall(lines)
    print out
```

EDIT: If you need to get the average of `RSSI` values do this:

```
    avg = sum(map(int,out))/len(map(int,out))
    print avg
```

Comment: This will return the values in a list so you can use them later or convert them into integers.

Comment: This works perfectly and allows me to print on screen and output to a file. Have you any links that will help me learn reg expressions? Cheers man.

Comment: Regular expression is not just for python and it is a very useful way of string parsing have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression
Just press the check mark if you find my answer useful. :)

Comment: Is there anyway I can grab the last RSSI value of the file and print just that using regex? @muradin

Comment: Yes, the code above will return you a list of matched occurrence, So you can get the last element just by `out[-1]` means (n-1) or the last element.

Comment: How do I get all of the values and put them in a list so I can find the average of them out? @muradin

Comment: The worst thing when you need help is to uncheck the true answer. My answer was true and you don't have the right to do this. According to you question i mentioned previously that the `out` type is a list and you can simply take an average `sum(out)/len(out)`. If you have any other questions post them with another title and do your job with responsibility. Belief me you can do that!

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. I will try the code tomorrow and report back. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: I get an error when trying to work the average out: rssiaverage = sum(out)/len(out). The error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: "int" and "str" @muradin

Answer (score 1):

use `find`

```
dumpfile = open("dumpscan.txt","r")
for x in dumpfile:
    if x.find("RSSI:")>=0:
        print x
```

`str.find` if its find the string returns the posiotion else -1

demo:

```
>>> f = open('dumpscan.txt')
>>> for x in f:
...     if x.find('RSSI') >=0:
...         print x
... 
RSSI: -72

RSSI: -70
```

Comment: This does not print anything back. If i take the >=0 away it prints the entire file.

Comment: @JonathanDavies it must print , i have given demo too

Comment: Either I am doing something wrong or this does not work. It is not printing anything.

Comment: dumpfile = open("dumpscan.txt","r")
for x in dumpfile:
    if x.find("RSSI:")>=0:
        print x

@Hackoholic I have also tried it without the "r" and nothing prints.

Comment: It may be the file. The file I gave you is a sample of a large file of around 100 RSSIs. @Hackaholic